# Can the ideal gas law be rewritten to include the entropy instead of either temperature, pressure, or volume?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, ideal-gas

The equation of state for and ideal gas states, $PV = mRT$. Since entropy is a state variable, can the equation of state be rewritten in terms of entropy?

Comment: The $pV=RT$ is the so-called thermal equation of state and it is mostly independent of the so-called caloric equation of state, that is the relationship between the internal energy and the other parameters $T,V,p$. The caloric equation of state $U=f_1(T,V)$ or $U=f_2(p,V)$ can also be expressed as $S=g_1(T,V)$ or $S=g_2(p,V)$, but more commonly as $C_v=h_1(T,V)$ where $C_v$ is the heat capacity. An ideal gas is *defined* as one whose internal energy depends only on the temperature $U=f_3(T)$ but even that cannot be derived form the $pV=RT$. Once you have the $C_v=h_1(T)$ function you can do it

Comment: @hyportnex I have edited my post to "equation of state" instead of "ideal gas law".

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking: (1) If you are asking, can we replace $P$ or $T$ or $V$ in the ideal-gas law with $S$, the answer is yes, and it was given by Mauricio.  (2) If the question is, can I get $S$ from the derivatives of of $P=h(T,V)$, the answer is no, and it was given by hyportnex. (3) Still, if the question is, can I get $S$ if I know the equation of state ideal-gas or other, the answer is also yes. So, exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Themis I was asking more with regard to (1), as per your comment. All the answers received are very insightful though. By the way, is there a reason for using the letter "h" to signify the function P = h(T,V)? Please excuse the naivete. Regards

Comment: @pa_blo Ok, then the answer is is a simple yes. As for using $h$, I followed hyportnex who used different symbols for the various functions. Normally we would simply write $P = P(T,V)$ and we mean the same thing,

Answer (score 12):

I think you're perhaps looking for a **constitutive equation** for the ideal gas in terms of entropy $S$, rather than an [equation of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state) (which has an intensive parameter such as temperature $T$ or pressure $P$ on the right-hand side, in contrast to the entropy, which is extensive).

The [fundamental relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_thermodynamic_relation) can just as well be written to highlight the entropy as

$$dS=\frac{1}{T}dU+\frac{P}{T}dV=\frac{1}{T}dH-\frac{V}{T}dP,$$

with internal energy $U$ and enthalpy $H$. Integrating and applying the definitions $c_V\equiv\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V$ and $c_P\equiv\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_P$ for the constant-volume and constant-pressure specific heats and number of moles $n$, along with the ideal gas equation of state $P=\frac{nRT}{V}$ (gas constant $R$), we have

$$S(V,T)=S_0+nc_V\ln\frac{T}{T_0}+nR\ln\frac{V}{V_0};$$

$$S(P,T)=S_0+nc_P\ln\frac{T}{T_0}+nR\ln\frac{P_0}{P}.$$

It’s a useful thermodynamics exercise to show that all the equations in the existing answers on this page are equivalent, with the Sackur–Tetrode equation specifying $c_V$ for the monatomic case and some equations requiring nondimensionalization within the logarithm, which introduces reference state variables such as $T_0$.

Comment: +1 Somehow I've never seen entropy presented this way before. I feel like there should be a log in the third term, since entropy scales with $\ln(V)$. Is that right?

Comment: It is! Thank you; I corrected the error.

Answer (score 5):

The $pV=RT$ is the so-called thermal equation of state and it is mostly independent of the so-called caloric equation of state, that is the relationship between the internal energy and the other parameters $T,V,p$. The caloric equation of state $U=f_1(T,V)$ or $U=f_2(p,V)$ can also be expressed as $S=g1(T,V)$ or $S=g_2(p,V)$, but more commonly as $Cv=h_1(T,V)$ where $C_v$ is the heat capacity. An ideal gas is defined as one whose internal energy depends only on the temperature $U=f_3(T)$ but even that cannot be derived from the $pV=RT$. Once you have the $C_v=h_1(T)$ function the entropy $S$ can be expressed by integrating the caloric equation of state using the thermal equation of state.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, any closed system in thermodynamics equilibrium can be described without any loss of generality from its entropy. The formula for the entropy of an ideal monoatomic gas is called the [Sackur-Tetrode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sackur%E2%80%93Tetrode_equation). It is given by

$$S = {k N}\ln
\left[ \frac VN \left(\frac{4\pi m}{3h^2}\frac {U}N\right)^{3/2}\right]+
{\frac 52}{k N}$$
where $V$ is the volume, $N$ the number of gas particles, $U=3NkT/2$ is the internal energy, $m$ the mass of the particles, $U$ the internal energy, $h$ Planck's constant and $k$ Boltzmann's constant (replace $k\to R$ and $N\to n$ if you want to use moles).

Knowning that
$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_{U,N}=\frac pT$$
one can recover the ideal gas law ($pV=kNT$).

Answer (score 4):

You could start from the hydrodynamic version of the entropy as $$ s = k_B \;c_V\; \ln(P/\rho^{\gamma})$$
where $\gamma$ is the adiabatic index.
You can then construct a different form of s by using $$ P = \rho k_B T/m  $$
with which you end up with $$s =k_B\;c_V\;\ln(k_BT/(m \rho^{\gamma-1})) .$$
You can reverse this excercise to get a functional form of $P(s,T)$.

Comment: There must be more to this equation, as we can’t take the logarithm of a quantity with units.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Well, I skipped an integration constant which is essentially $s_0 = k_B c_V ln(P_0/\rho_0^{\gamma})$, which would be pulled into the $ln$ to non-dimensionalize it.

Comment: I believe that would reconcile our different equations, in conjunction with the relations [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_process).

Comment: @Chemomechanics: Our formulations should be equivalent. My first Eqn. is the constant of motion plopping out from the third Euler-equation (i.e. the hydrodynamic energy equation) which itself is just a reformulation of your first equation.